# How can I determine if a variable exists from within the Groovy code running in the Scripting Engine?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, scripting, java-scripting-engine

How can I determine if a variable exists from within the Groovy code running in the Scripting Engine?

The variable was put by [ScriptEngine's put method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvement for the existing solution given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56306660/3158217 -

```
def defaultIfInexistent(varName, defaultValue){
    try{
        varName.toString()
        return varName
    }catch(ex){
        return defaultValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45):

In a [groovy.lang.Script](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html) there is a method `public Binding getBinding()`. And [groovy.lang.Binding](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) has method `public boolean hasVariable(String name)`.

Thus you can simply check variable existence like:

```
if (binding.hasVariable('superVariable')) {
// your code here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
// Example usage: defaultIfInexistent({myVar}, "default")
def defaultIfInexistent(varNameExpr, defaultValue) {
    try {
        varNameExpr()
    } catch (exc) {
        defaultValue
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is better because it works around the Jenkins security sandbox.

Comment: What does `varNameExpr()` do?

Comment: Better than what? The binding.hasVariable function works and seems much cleaner

Answer (score 7):

Variables injected by the Scripting Engine are held within
`binding.variables`, so you can e.g. check for variable named `xx`:

```
if (binding.variables["xx"]) ...
```

Comment: In my context (Jenkins) I got the error : org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.Binding getVariables.  The other answer didn't work either, but it wasn't a security problem.

Comment: This is rather a Jenkins issue. Maybe you should ask a new question and mark it with *Jenkins* tag.

Comment: @andrewlorien If you had catched such an error, you can go to Jenkins settings, "In-process Script Approval" and approve this script.

Comment: You can also move such code to a Shared Library. For pipeline projects at least: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/