# Jenkinsfile if (env.someBool.toBoolean() != false) against possible null

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to get an if statement run if `env.someBool.toBoolean()` returns null or true. However the toBoolean() causes it to throw if it's null.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method toBoolean() on null object`

I would say that null does not equal false, so should return true, but it throws before it can come to such a conclusion.

A colleague who works with Jira's groovy linked me to [this as a possible way forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465028/how-can-i-determine-if-a-variable-exists-from-within-the-groovy-code-running-in), but I can't see how to adapt it to Jenkinsfile env.xyz

Comment: `if(env.someBool?.toBoolean()) ...`

Comment: http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator

Answer (score 0):

As @dagett said, the Safe Navigation Operator did the trick.